# marionette controller object, create dynamic prototype methods?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype, marionette

I am using marionette for an app that has many pagess. The controller/router method is repetitive, in each method the view is instantiated and the appRegion shows the view.

I would like to create the methods inside a loop.

```
var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({});

for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
  // build dynamic controller methods
}
```

I have been learning about object prototypes and I think I can do something like.

```
var pages = [{'pageButtons': Buttons},{'pageLogin': Login}];
for(var page in pages) {
  for(var method in pages[page]) {
    console.log(method) // write dynamic method here?
  }
}
```

My question is the above block, how do I finish it, can I add new methods in a loop? Is there a way to simplify this repetitive task of adding the same code over and over?

Comment: Just curious, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're totally on the right track. I also think, there's actually two problems here. You outlined the first, and the second, would be to create and provide routes dynamically to your `Router`.

#### Setting up your `Controller` view methods and Router

I was thinking to modify your reference `pages` object like this:

```
var pages = [
  {'pageButtons': Buttons, route: 'buttons'},
  {'pageLogin': Login, route: 'login'}
];
```

Next we declare the controller and add the dynamic methods

```
var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({}),
    Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({});

for(var page in pages) {
  for(var method in pages[page]) {
    // Each method will be have a pointer in
    // Controller.pagemethod, e.g. Controller.pageButtonsButtons
    Controller[page + method] = pages[page][method];
    // And now we set up the Router
    // e.g. a url of http://appdomain#pagesButton will map to 
    // a method with name 'pageButtonsButtons'
    Router[page] = page + method;
  }
}
```

Of course, the sky's the limit to the extent that you customize the "method factory". The more properties you add in your reference `pages` object the more specific you factory can be.

I also want to **note** that here we're not adding the methods to the `Controller`'s prototype, only for the sake of simplicity. And I think we can get away with it here because commonly `Controller`s are instantiated once and we don't necessarily need the productivity gain of extending the prototype. However, there's not functional difference if you do.

Comment: I havent checked SO in days, I thought this question was a lost cause. Cool man that looks awesome, let me try that out and mess around with it, I think it should simplify the process, or it might make it more confusing, who knows, it's worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to define the page settings in an object and then dynamically generate the routes and controller functions, consider this:

```
var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
  mainRegion: "#main"
});

// Sample custom view
var view = Marionette.ItemView.extend({custom: 'properties'});

// Main config object
var pages = {
    "page/a": {view: view, msg: "route a!", controllerFunc: "pageA", templateSelector: "#pageA"},
    "page/b": {view: view, msg: "route b!", controllerFunc: "pageB", templateSelector: "#pageB"},
    "page/c": {view: view, msg: "route c!", controllerFunc: "pageC", templateSelector: "#pageC"}
};

var controller = {}; // Marionette.Controller is deprecated, just use a plain js object.
var routes = {};

// Populate controller and routes via routeConfigs
_.each(pages, function (page, route, list){

    // An IIFE, read more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

    // Return a function
    controller[page.controllerFunc] = (function(page){
      return function() {

        // Instantiate a new view based on the template selector
        app.mainRegion.show(new (page.view)({template: page.templateSelector}));

        // A log just to demonstrate what you can do with the other attributes.
        console.log('Message = ', page.msg);
      };
    })(page);

    // Populate routes too
    routes[route] = page.controllerFunc;
});

// The actual appRouter
var router = new Marionette.AppRouter({
  controller: controller,
  appRoutes: routes
});

app.start();
Backbone.history.start();

// Test route B
Backbone.history.navigate('page/b', true);
```

jsfiddle for you to play around. http://jsfiddle.net/RyanTanZH/vts85znw/8/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a function to hold your common actions.

```
var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
  mainRegion: "#main"
});

// Sample custom view
var view = Marionette.ItemView.extend({custom: 'properties'});

// Main config object
var pages = {
    "page/a": {view: view, msg: "route a!", controllerFunc: "pageA", templateSelector: "#pageA"},
    "page/b": {view: view, msg: "route b!", controllerFunc: "pageB", templateSelector: "#pageB"},
    "page/c": {view: view, msg: "route c!", controllerFunc: "pageC", templateSelector: "#pageC"}
};

// Marionette.Controller is deprecated, just use a plain js object.
var controller = {
    baseAction: function (config){

        // View options
        var viewOptions = {template: config.templateSelector};

        // Instantiate a new view based on the template selector
        app.mainRegion.show(new (config.view)(viewOptions));

        // A log to check the values
        console.log('config = ', config);
    }
}; 
var routes = {};

// Populate controller and routes via routeConfigs
_.each(pages, function (page, route, list){

    // Return a function
    controller[page.controllerFunc] = (function(page){

      // An IIFE, read more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression
      return function() {
        controller.baseAction(page);
      };
    })(page);

    // Populate routes too
    routes[route] = page.controllerFunc;
});

// The actual appRouter
var router = new Marionette.AppRouter({
  controller: controller,
  appRoutes: routes
});

app.start();
Backbone.history.start();

// Test route A
Backbone.history.navigate('page/a', true);
```

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyanTanZH/crbdu51w/1/